# MATLAB not evaluating integral

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration, integral

MATLAB gives me the same expression back.
Here's my code

```
syms tau alpha phi
f = sign(alpha*cos(phi))*(abs(alpha*cos(phi)) - 2.5*(alpha*cos(phi))^2);
F=f*sin(phi);
int(F,phi, [pi/2, acos(tau/alpha)])
```

I did plug in the values of variables tau and alpha but it still gives me the same expression back. Anyone know how to solve it? Or some other numerical method which could give me answer in these symbols? Will wolfram-mathematica help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica

```
Integrate[(Sign[alpha*Cos[phi]]*(Abs[alpha*Cos[phi]] - 5/2*
  (alpha*Cos[phi])^2))*Sin[phi], {phi, Pi/2, ArcCos[tau/alpha]}]
```

(*  ConditionalExpression[-(tau^2/(2 alpha)) + (5 alpha^3 Abs[tau]^3)/
       (6 Abs[alpha]^4), ArcCos[tau/alpha] \[Element] Reals]  *)

Thus the result is the expression inside the ConditionalExpression if the ArcCos[tau/alpha] is an element of the reals.

If you could specify something like -1<=tau/alpha<=1 && 0<=tau then it can provide an even simpler result, (tau^2 (-3 + 5 tau))/(6 alpha)

Please verify this before you depend on it.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks a lot for your help.
The conditions that you have specified are right for my work, so I can enter them.
But the problem is when I run your script in mathematica, it gives me an error instead of the answer. 
This is the error "SSH encountered an error with the local network setup while launching kernel 'New Kernel'. Error code = 104.". I'm really a beginner when it comes to mathematica, could you please help me fix this? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Let's try this: Go to https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/ and wait for it to load. Click on "Create a New Notebook" in the lower right and wait for it to stabilize. Then click in the large white area and paste Assuming[alpha>tau>0,Integrate[(Sign[alpha* Cos[phi]]* (Abs[alpha* Cos[phi]] -5/2* (alpha* Cos[phi])^2))* Sin[phi],{phi,Pi/2,ArcCos[tau/alpha]}]] and wait for it to stabilize. Click on "Evaluation" on the menu bar and then on "Evaluate all cells" and wait. See if this works. Please do not abuse this service. There is lots more about signing in, subscribing, etc, that I don't use.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
syms tau alpha phi
f = sign(alpha*cos(phi))*(abs(alpha*cos(phi)) - 2.5*(alpha*cos(phi))^2);
```

will just generate another symbolic variable. Your goal however is to specify a symbolic function and for that you have to specify the function arguments:

```
syms tau alpha phi
f(tau,alpha,phi) = sign(alpha*cos(phi))*(abs(alpha*cos(phi)) - 2.5*(alpha*cos(phi))^2);
F(tau,alpha,phi) =f*sin(phi);
```

Then you can calculate the integral with

```
R = int(F,phi, [pi/2, acos(tau/alpha)])
```

Since your integral is dependent on `tau` and `alpha`, `R` is again a symbolic function `R(tau,alpha)`.

Alternatively you could just specify the arguments at the end, e.g.

```
syms tau alpha phi
f = sign(alpha*cos(phi))*(abs(alpha*cos(phi)) - 2.5*(alpha*cos(phi))^2);
F=f*sin(phi);
R(tau,alpha) = int(F,phi, [pi/2, acos(tau/alpha)])
```

But I personally find that less clean.

Note that you could also write F directly as

```
F(tau,alpha,phi) = sin(phi)*(sign(alpha*cos(phi))*(abs(alpha*cos(phi)) - 2.5*(alpha*cos(phi))^2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it doesn't solve the problem, it gives me the same answer as the previous, i.e. its not integrating the said function and returning me the same expression again.

Comment: @UzairKhan You have to call the integrated function with some arguments, e.g. `x = double(R(1,2))` gives the integral with `tau = 1` and  `alpha = 2`.